# How do I make this restart after the number is guessed?

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
from random import random, randint
def restart():
    number = randint(1, 10)
    print(number)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def start():
        return 'What number am I?'

    @app.route(f'/{number}')
    def found():
        return 'You found me!'

    @app.route('/<num>')
    def check(num):
        lownum = int(num)
        if lownum < number:
            return 'Too Low!'
        if lownum > number:
            return 'Too High!'

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)

restart()
```

Detecting if the number is high or low works fine it's just I want to make it make a new number after the previous number is found. I there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You need to run `number = randint(1, 10)` again to override the value once it is found.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `found()` route, check for a matching number in `check()`. Then you can reset `number` when then guess the number.

Also, `if __name__ == "__main__":` is normally put at top-level, not inside the function.

```
from flask import Flask
from random import random, randint
def restart():
    number = randint(1, 10)
    print(number)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def start():
        return 'What number am I?'

    @app.route('/<num>')
    def check(num):
        nonlocal number
        lownum = int(num)
        if lownum < number:
            return 'Too Low!'
        if lownum > number:
            return 'Too High!'
        number = randint(1, 10)
        return 'You found me!'

    app.run(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    restart()
```